# How do i install Nvidia Drivers in 12.10 (new to ubuntu)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How do I install extra drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-extra-drivers)

Hey Guys I just installed (Dual Booted) Ubuntu 12.10 64 Bit on my Machine. (now running 32 Bit Ubuntu 12.10)

#### Specs:

ASUS M5A97 Mobo
16 GB of AMD Entertainment Ram
Gigabyte Geforce 550 GTX TI
AMD Bulldozer 8120 Eight-Core CPU

Any ways I was just wondering how i could install the latest Nvidia Drivers for my card

Thanks